# Socket module does not work in my Python

Tags: python, http, sockets

Very simple.

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('http://yahoo.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very simple.

"http://yahoo.com" is not a host name. Try `socket.gethostbyname('yahoo.com')` :)

Answer (score 2):

It is because, quite frankly, `http://yahoo.com` is in no way a *domain name*, which `gethostbyname` expects from you. `http://yahoo.com` is an URL.

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname("yahoo.com")
'69.147.114.224'
```

Comment: how is it not really correct? you mean "in no way" is not grammatically correct? :P In that case, I apologize. Otherwise, `http://yahoo.com` is *not* a valid domain name at all.